# Java - Where to put Timer code in my file?

Tags: java, user-interface, clock

Let's say I have the following skeleton for a GUI that works with a clock (I may be importing more than I need to; I created this from a much larger file):

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class clock extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    Container c;
    JLabel year, month, date, hour, minute, second;

    public clock(Calendar cal)
    {
        //set up GUI; initialize and add all 6 JLabels
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
        clock c = new clock(current);
    }
}
```

I want to have the clock update every second.  From what I understand, this is [at least part of] the code that I need:

```
ActionListener listener = new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        cal.
        year.setText("year: " +cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        month.setText("month: " +cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        date.setText("date: " +cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        hour.setText("hour: " +cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        minute.setText("minute: " +cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        second.setText("second: " +cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer(500, listener);
timer.setInitialDelay(0);
timer.start();
```

Does this second block of code go in the constructor, or outside of both the constructor and main?  I've tried both and have gotten different errors for each.  I've read something about needing *@Override* for this to work, but I'm not familiar with that.  Also, is this all the code I need for my timer to work, or is there more (and if so, what)?  I've seen an example on here of a clock that did basically what I'm trying to do, but it used all kinds of other things that I've never been taught (*runnable*, *try*, *catch*, etc.), so I'd like to do it with what I know if possible.

I realize that I'll probably need to make my Calendar object global for the ActionListener to access it if that block of code goes outside of the constructor.

EDIT: I updated the actionPerformed method to include an updating of the Calendar.  I also provided the errors I was getting (note that the line numbers are incorrect since my actual constructor contains many more lines than the skeleton one on here):

*when I place the second block of code inside the constructor:*

```
clock.java:10: error: clock is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class clock extends JFrame implements ActionListener
       ^
```

*when I place the second block of code outside of the constructor:*

```
clock.java:59: error: <identifier> expected
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
                         ^
clock.java:59: error: illegal start of type
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
                          ^
clock.java:60: error: <identifier> expected
    timer.start();
               ^
```

EDIT2: Here are the exceptions I am getting from MadProgrammer's solution:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Clock$1.actionPerformed(clock.java:18)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:313)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:245)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

EDIT3: Error from @MadProgrammer's updated solution:

```
Clock.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());  
                  ^
  symbol:   class FlowLayout
  location: class Clock
```

Comment: Your execution should not be blocked by the starting of the `Timer`. Take a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html. What exactly are the errors that you mentioned? Can you add more details to your question (e.g. stacktrace)?

Comment: Do you want to start the `Timer` when the class is constructed or do you want to have control over it?  Oh and you never update `Calendar` so it's always going to return back the same result it started with

Comment: @hotzst I've read that before, but it didn't really help me.  I updated my post to include my errors.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I want to start it when I make the call to my constructor in main.  I added in a line that updates the Calendar.

Comment: There are two `Timer`s in the API, `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer`, this is the one you want, but it's been resolved to `java.util.Timer`.  You can declear it absolutely, `java.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swng.Timer(...)`.  You also need to implement the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method, as required by the `ActionListener`

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks.  So I want to put `javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.timer (500, listener);` instead of my current line that declares the timer?  Also, for what I want, where do I put the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent)` method, `ActionListener`, and my timer declaration?  I'm still getting the same errors that I included in my edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
clock.java:59: error: <identifier> expected
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
                         ^
clock.java:59: error: illegal start of type
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
                          ^
clock.java:60: error: <identifier> expected
    timer.start();
```

would indicate that you're importing the wrong `Timer`.  Java has two, `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer`, which is the one you want.

Normally, I don't use wildcard imports for this reason, but then my IDE's auto import function use absolute imports as well.

But you could either use

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
```

or use an absolute declaration like...

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, listener);
```

depending on your needs (you often end up here when using `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` :P)

This...

```
clock.java:10: error: clock is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
public class clock extends JFrame implements ActionListener
```

would indicate that you've not implemented the requirements of the `ActionListener` interface contract.  In your case I don't think you actually need it, as you're making your own `ActionListener` internally

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Clock extends JFrame {

    JLabel year, month, date, hour, minute, second;

    public Clock(Calendar cal) {
        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                cal.setTime(new Date());
                updateTime(cal);
            }
        };

        year = new JLabel();
        month = new JLabel();
        date = new JLabel();
        hour = new JLabel();
        minute = new JLabel();
        second = new JLabel();

        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(year);
        add(month);
        add(date);
        add(hour);
        add(minute);
        add(second);

        updateTime(cal);

        javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(500, listener);
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }

    protected void updateTime(Calendar cal) {
        year.setText("year: " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        month.setText("month: " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        date.setText("date: " + cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
        hour.setText("hour: " + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        minute.setText("minute: " + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        second.setText("second: " + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Clock();
    }

    public Clock() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();
                Clock frame = new Clock(current);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, while it does compile, I get no clock - just get a bunch of exceptions.  They're too long to post in this comment, so I have edited them into the original post (see EDIT2).

Comment: @NickH88 None of the components had been initialised, this is what you get for letting your 3 year old try and answer the question for you

Comment: I should have seen that for myself, lol.  This one returns just 1 error (one that seems simple but puzzles me), which I edited into the first post (EDIT3) for sake of formatting.

Comment: Add import java.awt.FlowLayout

Comment: Thanks.  It runs without errors now, but there's no clock... just an indefinitely-running program that does seemingly nothing.

Comment: Did you try making the frame visible?